d3js pie chart with rounded segments
I am trying to experiment with different styles for the d3.js charts I have -- I am unsure how you would round the segments of the pie chart to mirror this design example.
Labels in rounded boxes, segments slightly gapped with rounded edges - in this design the segments have different heights maybe relating to the value?

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/magical-wiles-forked-cxhmky
the current code for a regular pie
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import './PieChart1.scss';

class PieChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            theme: this.props.theme ? this.props.theme : ['#bde0fe', '#2698f9', '#71bcfd', '#f1f8fe']
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var $this = this.myRef.current;

        d3.select($this)
            .selectAll('svg')
            .remove();

        const data = this.props.data;

        const width = parseInt(this.props.width, 10),
            height = parseInt(this.props.height, 10),
            radius = parseInt(this.props.r, 10),
            innerradius = parseInt(this.props.ir, 10);

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.state.theme);

        var arc = d3
            .arc()
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .innerRadius(innerradius);

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.total = +d.value;
        });

        var pie = d3
            .pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) {
                return d.total;
            });

        var svg = d3
            .select($this)
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'piechart')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

        var segments = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'segments');

        var slices = segments
            .selectAll('.arc')
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc');

        slices
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .transition()
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle+0.1, d.endAngle);
                return function(t) {
                    d.endAngle = i(t);
                    return arc(d);
                }
            });

    }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.myRef} className="PieChart" />;
    }
}
export default PieChart;

research into rounded corners
https://medium.com/@bryony_17728/d3-donut-rounded-corners-the-mystery-of-pi-f772121d87a6
Add border-radius property to D3js Donut Chart
"can apply a corner radius to a d3 arc which allows rounding on the corners:"
let arc = d3.svg
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(23)
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .cornerRadius(10);


"If you apply the cornerRadius to only the darkened arc - the other
arc won't fill in the background behind the rounded corners. Instead,
we could append a circular arc (full donut) and place the darkened arc
on top with rounding (my example doesn't adapt your code, just shows
how that it can be done, also with d3v4 which uses d3.arc() rather
than d3.svg.arc() ):"



var backgroundArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(30)
  .outerRadius(50)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(Math.PI*2);
  
var mainArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(30)
  .outerRadius(50)
  .cornerRadius(10)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(function(d) { return d/100*Math.PI* 2 });
  
var data = [10,20,30,40,50] // percents.
  
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 600)
  .attr("height", 200);
  
var charts = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i) { 
     return "translate("+(i*100+50)+",100)";
  });
  
charts.append("path")
  .attr("d", backgroundArc)
  .attr("fill","#ccc")

charts.append("path")
  .attr("d", mainArc) 
  .attr("fill","orange")
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>



this version rounds just the top corners

Doughnut chart with only top corners rounded


let data = [
    {name: "A", value: 100 },
    {name: "B", value: 200 },
    {name: "C", value: 300 },
    {name: "D", value: 400 },
  ]
  
  const width = 400;
  const radius = 150;
  const height = 400;

  const arc = d3.customArc()
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.67)
      .outerRadius(radius - 1)
      .cornerRadius(20);

  const pie = d3.pie()
      .padAngle(1 / radius)
      .sort(null)
      .value(d => d.value);

  const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
      .range(d3.quantize(t => d3.interpolateSpectral(t * 0.8 + 0.1), data.length).reverse());

  const svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;");
      


  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll()
    .data(pie(data))
    .join("path")
      .attr("fill", d => color(d.data.name))
      .attr("d", arc)
    .append("title")
      .text(d => `${d.data.name}: ${d.data.value.toLocaleString()}`);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 12)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .selectAll()
    .data(pie(data))
    .join("text")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${arc.centroid(d)})`)
      .call(text => text.append("tspan")
          .attr("y", "-0.4em")
          .attr("font-weight", "bold")
          .text(d => d.data.name))
      .call(text => text.filter(d => (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) > 0.25).append("tspan")
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", "0.7em")
          .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
          .text(d => d.data.value.toLocaleString("en-US")));
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3customArc.js"></script>

<script>

(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports, require('d3-path')) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports', 'd3-path'], factory) :
  (factory((global.d3 = global.d3 || {}),global.d3));
}(this, (function (exports,d3Path) { 'use strict';


var constant = function(x) {
  return function constant() {
    return x;
  };
};

var epsilon = 1e-12;
var pi = Math.PI;
var halfPi = pi / 2;
var tau = 2 * pi;

var atan2 = Math.atan2;
var asin = Math.asin;
var cos = Math.cos;
var sin = Math.sin;
var acos = Math.acos;
var atan = Math.atan;
var abs = Math.abs;
var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
var min = Math.min;
var max = Math.max;

function withPath(shape) {
  let digits = 3;

  shape.digits = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return digits;
    if (_ == null) {
      digits = null;
    } else {
      const d = floor(_);
      if (!(d >= 0)) throw new RangeError(`invalid digits: ${_}`);
      digits = d;
    }
    return shape;
  };

  return () => new d3.path(digits);
}


function arcInnerRadius(d) {
  return d.innerRadius;
}

function arcOuterRadius(d) {
  return d.outerRadius;
}

function arcStartAngle(d) {
  return d.startAngle;
}

function arcEndAngle(d) {
  return d.endAngle;
}

function arcPadAngle(d) {
  return d && d.padAngle; // Note: optional!
}

function intersect(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
  var x10 = x1 - x0, y10 = y1 - y0,
      x32 = x3 - x2, y32 = y3 - y2,
      t = y32 * x10 - x32 * y10;
  if (t * t < epsilon) return;
  t = (x32 * (y0 - y2) - y32 * (x0 - x2)) / t;
  return [x0 + t * x10, y0 + t * y10];
}

// Compute perpendicular offset line of length rc.
// http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html
function cornerTangents(x0, y0, x1, y1, r1, rc, cw) {
  var x01 = x0 - x1,
      y01 = y0 - y1,
      lo = (cw ? rc : -rc) / sqrt(x01 * x01 + y01 * y01),
      ox = lo * y01,
      oy = -lo * x01,
      x11 = x0 + ox,
      y11 = y0 + oy,
      x10 = x1 + ox,
      y10 = y1 + oy,
      x00 = (x11 + x10) / 2,
      y00 = (y11 + y10) / 2,
      dx = x10 - x11,
      dy = y10 - y11,
      d2 = dx * dx + dy * dy,
      r = r1 - rc,
      D = x11 * y10 - x10 * y11,
      d = (dy < 0 ? -1 : 1) * sqrt(max(0, r * r * d2 - D * D)),
      cx0 = (D * dy - dx * d) / d2,
      cy0 = (-D * dx - dy * d) / d2,
      cx1 = (D * dy + dx * d) / d2,
      cy1 = (-D * dx + dy * d) / d2,
      dx0 = cx0 - x00,
      dy0 = cy0 - y00,
      dx1 = cx1 - x00,
      dy1 = cy1 - y00;

  // Pick the closer of the two intersection points.
  // TODO Is there a faster way to determine which intersection to use?
  if (dx0 * dx0 + dy0 * dy0 > dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1) cx0 = cx1, cy0 = cy1;

  return {
    cx: cx0,
    cy: cy0,
    x01: -ox,
    y01: -oy,
    x11: cx0 * (r1 / r - 1),
    y11: cy0 * (r1 / r - 1)
  };
}

var customArc = function() {
  var innerRadius = arcInnerRadius,
      outerRadius = arcOuterRadius,
      cornerRadius = constant(0),
      padRadius = null,
      startAngle = arcStartAngle,
      endAngle = arcEndAngle,
      padAngle = arcPadAngle,
      context = null,
      path = withPath(customArc);

  function customArc() {
    var buffer,
        r,
        r0 = +innerRadius.apply(this, arguments),
        r1 = +outerRadius.apply(this, arguments),
        a0 = startAngle.apply(this, arguments) - halfPi,
        a1 = endAngle.apply(this, arguments) - halfPi,
        da = abs(a1 - a0),
        cw = a1 > a0;

    if (!context) context = buffer = path();

    // Ensure that the outer radius is always larger than the inner radius.
    if (r1 < r0) r = r1, r1 = r0, r0 = r;

    // Is it a point?
    if (!(r1 > epsilon)) context.moveTo(0, 0);

    // Or is it a circle or annulus?
    else if (da > tau - epsilon) {
      context.moveTo(r1 * cos(a0), r1 * sin(a0));
      context.arc(0, 0, r1, a0, a1, !cw);
      if (r0 > epsilon) {
        context.moveTo(r0 * cos(a1), r0 * sin(a1));
        context.arc(0, 0, r0, a1, a0, cw);
      }
    }

    // Or is it a circular or annular sector?
    else {
      var a01 = a0,
          a11 = a1,
          a00 = a0,
          a10 = a1,
          da0 = da,
          da1 = da,
          ap = padAngle.apply(this, arguments) / 2,
          rp = (ap > epsilon) && (padRadius ? +padRadius.apply(this, arguments) : sqrt(r0 * r0 + r1 * r1)),
          rc = min(abs(r1 - r0) / 2, +cornerRadius.apply(this, arguments)),
          rc0 = rc,
          rc1 = rc,
          t0,
          t1;

      // Apply padding? Note that since r1 ≥ r0, da1 ≥ da0.
      if (rp > epsilon) {
        var p0 = asin(rp / r0 * sin(ap)),
            p1 = asin(rp / r1 * sin(ap));
        if ((da0 -= p0 * 2) > epsilon) p0 *= (cw ? 1 : -1), a00 += p0, a10 -= p0;
        else da0 = 0, a00 = a10 = (a0 + a1) / 2;
        if ((da1 -= p1 * 2) > epsilon) p1 *= (cw ? 1 : -1), a01 += p1, a11 -= p1;
        else da1 = 0, a01 = a11 = (a0 + a1) / 2;
      }

      var x01 = r1 * cos(a01),
          y01 = r1 * sin(a01),
          x10 = r0 * cos(a10),
          y10 = r0 * sin(a10);

      // Apply rounded corners?
      if (rc > epsilon) {
        var x11 = r1 * cos(a11),
            y11 = r1 * sin(a11),
            x00 = r0 * cos(a00),
            y00 = r0 * sin(a00),
            oc;

        // Restrict the corner radius according to the sector angle. If this
        // intersection fails, it’s probably because the arc is too small, so
        // disable the corner radius entirely.
        if (da < pi) {
          if (oc = intersect(x01, y01, x00, y00, x11, y11, x10, y10)) {
            var ax = x01 - oc[0],
                ay = y01 - oc[1],
                bx = x11 - oc[0],
                by = y11 - oc[1],
                kc = 1 / sin(acos((ax * bx + ay * by) / (sqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay) * sqrt(bx * bx + by * by))) / 2),
                lc = sqrt(oc[0] * oc[0] + oc[1] * oc[1]);
            rc0 = min(rc, (r0 - lc) / (kc - 1));
            rc1 = min(rc, (r1 - lc) / (kc + 1));
          } else {
            rc0 = rc1 = 0;
          }
        }
      }

      // Is the sector collapsed to a line?
      if (!(da1 > epsilon)) context.moveTo(x01, y01);

      // Does the sector’s outer ring have rounded corners?
      else if (rc1 > epsilon) {
        t0 = cornerTangents(x00, y00, x01, y01, r1, rc1, cw);
        t1 = cornerTangents(x11, y11, x10, y10, r1, rc1, cw);

        context.moveTo(t0.cx + t0.x01, t0.cy + t0.y01);

        // Have the corners merged?
        if (rc1 < rc) context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc1, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);

        // Otherwise, draw the two corners and the ring.
        else {
          context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc1, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t0.y11, t0.x11), !cw);
          context.arc(0, 0, r1, atan2(t0.cy + t0.y11, t0.cx + t0.x11), atan2(t1.cy + t1.y11, t1.cx + t1.x11), !cw);
          context.arc(t1.cx, t1.cy, rc1, atan2(t1.y11, t1.x11), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);
        }
      }

      // Or is the outer ring just a circular arc?
      else context.moveTo(x01, y01), context.arc(0, 0, r1, a01, a11, !cw);

      // Is there no inner ring, and it’s a circular sector?
      // Or perhaps it’s an annular sector collapsed due to padding?
      if (!(r0 > epsilon) || !(da0 > epsilon)) context.lineTo(x10, y10);

      // Does the sector’s inner ring (or point) have rounded corners?
      /* // Start Changes: Remove:
      else if (rc0 > epsilon) {
        t0 = cornerTangents(x10, y10, x11, y11, r0, -rc0, cw);
        t1 = cornerTangents(x01, y01, x00, y00, r0, -rc0, cw);

        context.lineTo(t0.cx + t0.x01, t0.cy + t0.y01);

        // Have the corners merged?
        if (rc0 < rc) context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc0, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);

        // Otherwise, draw the two corners and the ring.
        else {
          context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc0, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t0.y11, t0.x11), !cw);
          context.arc(0, 0, r0, atan2(t0.cy + t0.y11, t0.cx + t0.x11), atan2(t1.cy + t1.y11, t1.cx + t1.x11), cw);
          context.arc(t1.cx, t1.cy, rc0, atan2(t1.y11, t1.x11), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);
        }
      }
      */ // End Changes : Remove
      // Or is the inner ring just a circular arc?
      else context.arc(0, 0, r0, a10, a00, cw);
    }

    context.closePath();

    if (buffer) return context = null, buffer + "" || null;
  }

  customArc.centroid = function() {
    var r = (+innerRadius.apply(this, arguments) + +outerRadius.apply(this, arguments)) / 2,
        a = (+startAngle.apply(this, arguments) + +endAngle.apply(this, arguments)) / 2 - pi / 2;
    return [cos(a) * r, sin(a) * r];
  };

  customArc.innerRadius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (innerRadius = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : innerRadius;
  };

  customArc.outerRadius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (outerRadius = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : outerRadius;
  };

  customArc.cornerRadius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (cornerRadius = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) :cornerRadius;
  };
 

  customArc.padRadius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (padRadius = _ == null ? null : typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : padRadius;
  };

  customArc.startAngle = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (startAngle = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : startAngle;
  };

  customArc.endAngle = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (endAngle = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : endAngle;
  };

  customArc.padAngle = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (padAngle = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : padAngle;
  };

  customArc.context = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? ((context = _ == null ? null : _), customArc) : context;
  };

  return customArc;
}

exports.customArc = customArc;

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

})));

</script>




Is this question still relevant? If so, what is exactly the problem you need to solve? To render a piechart as in the first image or something else?

I wasn't able to style it as per design - the code rounds the outer parts of the segments but not the inner parts - then how to create/control a gap
